# Node.js send Get-Request with Json-Body

Tags: json, node.js, get

I'm using Node.js and need to send a get-request with a Json-Message in the body.

```
request = require('request-json');    
var client = request.createClient('http://ip');
client.get('/url', jsondata, function(err, res, body) {...
```

does not seem to send any Body-Data.

Any ideas how to manage?

Comment: are you using this as `request`? https://github.com/cozy/request-json

Comment: well, get method doesn't send data it GETs data, so you can't post/send data with get you should use POST `client.post`

Comment: problem is, i cant change the server code and it listens for get

Comment: are there any other npm plugins i can use for this task?

Comment: This https://www.npmjs.com/package/request look at `qs`param

Comment: Are you sure your server expects a body on a GET request?  Many clients don't support this, because varying the response to a GET request based on the body is a violation of HTTP/1.1

Comment: If the server is listening for a GET request, it's not going to be expecting a body at all. The only thing you can do is include a query string in the URI that attempts to represent the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try : https://github.com/request/request.
With that you do `request.get` or `request.post`.

Comment: I was able to realise it with it! Thanks

Comment: how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var request = require('request'), 
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1', 
    jsondata = {data1: 'x', data2: 'y'};

request({url: url, qs: jsondata}, function(err, response, body) {
  if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
  console.log(response);
});
```

`jsondata` should be an object (your query string to send to the server, in a browser would be `url/?data1=x&data2=y`)

Comment: Right, because `data1=x&data2=y` is a JSON request body... </sarcasm>